# Display different panel size in CardLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout

I have a `JPanel` (`cardLayoutPanel`) which layout is `CardLayout`.

I also have another 3 different panels (`firstPagePanel`, `secondPagePanel`, `thirdPagePanel`)

- `firstPagePanel` size is approximately around 450x400,
- `secondPagePanel` size is approximately around  800x600
- `thirdPagePanel` size is approximately around 1024x768

I `cardLayoutPanel.add` all 3 panels and I show `firstPagePanel` first as my view.

I want to let my program displayed the size of `firstPagePanel` first which is 450x400
and then if `secondPagePanel` is displayed, it will change the size to 800x600 and if `thirdPagePanel` is displayed,it will change the size to 1024,768

Instead of guessing what my 3 panel size should be, I used `frame.getPreferredSize()` but my first view will always take in the size of my `thirdPagePanel` which is 1024x768 instead of 450x400;

What can I do to resolve this issue?

```
public class MainFrame { 
    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
    private FirstPagePanel firstPagePanel = new FirstPagePanel(); 
    private SecondPagePanel secondPagePanel = new SecondPagePanel();    
    private ThirdPagePanel thirdPagePanel = new ThirdPagePanel();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Panel size test");

    public MainFrame() {
        cardLayoutPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
        cardLayoutPanel.add(firstPagePanel,"1");
        cardLayoutPanel.add(secondPagePanel,"2");
        cardLayoutPanel.add(thirdPagePanel,"3");
        cardLayout.show(cardLayoutPanel,"1");
        frame.add(cardLayoutPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.getPreferredSize();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would question why. This kind of "jumping" is very distraught and somewhat annoying as a user, IMHO

Comment: Because it will look wierd if I kept my firstPagePanel size as big as my thirdPagePanel size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to:

- Remove the current panel.
- Add the new panel.
- Pack the top level container.

### E.G.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ThreeSizeGui {

    public static void swapComponentsAndResizeUI(
            JComponent ui, 
            JComponent current,
            JComponent next) {
        ui.remove(current);
        ui.add(next);
        current = next;
        Component c = ui.getTopLevelAncestor();
        if (c instanceof Window) {
            Window w = (Window) c;
            w.pack();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JPanel ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
                ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(6, 6, 6, 6));

                JPanel controls = new JPanel(
                        new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
                ui.add(controls, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
                int s = 100;
                Dimension[] sizes = {
                    new Dimension(s * 4, s * 2),
                    new Dimension(s * 6, s * 3),
                    new Dimension(s * 8, s * 4)
                };
                final JComboBox cb = new JComboBox(sizes);
                controls.add(cb);
                final JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[sizes.length];
                for (int ii = 0; ii < sizes.length; ii++) {
                    Dimension d = sizes[ii];
                    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
                            d.width, d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
                    JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi));
                    p.add(l);
                    panels[ii] = p;
                }
                ItemListener sizeListener = new ItemListener() {

                    JPanel current = panels[0];

                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                        JPanel next = panels[cb.getSelectedIndex()];
                        swapComponentsAndResizeUI(ui, current, next);
                        current = next;
                    }
                };
                cb.addItemListener(sizeListener);

                ui.add(panels[0], BorderLayout.CENTER);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Three Sized Panels");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setContentPane(ui);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```